# angular 2 typescript custom error handler

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, listener

I'm implementing a custom error handler by extending the Angular 2 Error handler.  I'm able to do this and output to the console, but I want to trigger my modal window in the app.component instead.

error.module.ts

```
  import{ErrorHandler} from "@angular/core";
  import{NgModule} from "@angular/core";
  export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  call(error: any, stackTrace: any = null, reason: any = null) {
    // do something with the exception
    console.log("do something with the exception");
}

// I handle the given error.
public handleError( error: any ): void {
    console.log(JSON.parse(error._body).status_code);

   }

 }
 @NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: MyErrorHandler
    }
     ]
  })
 export class MyErrorModule {


 }
```

I then import the error handler:

app.module.ts

```
import {MyErrorHandler} from "./error.module";
import {MyErrorModule } from "./error.module";
```

Now in my app.Component I want to know when the error has occurred  get the error._body and open my modal window with :

```
this.childModal.show();
```

What is the proper way in app.component.ts to listen for the error event?

Comment: what does your console says.where have you defined the childModal? update your post with your app.Component.ts and the app.module.ts